# Passing a JavaScript value to PHP on completion of quiz

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a web page that allows users to complete quizzes. These quizzes use JavaScript to populate original questions each time it is run.

Disclaimer: JS Noob alert.

After the questions are completed, the user is given a final score via this function:

```
function CheckFinished(){
    var FB = '';
    var AllDone = true;
    for (var QNum=0; QNum<State.length; QNum++){
        if (State[QNum] != null){
            if (State[QNum][0] < 0){
                AllDone = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (AllDone == true){

//Report final score and submit if necessary
        NewScore();
        CalculateOverallScore();
        CalculateGrade();
        FB = YourScoreIs + ' ' + RealScore + '%. (' + Grade + ')';
        if (ShowCorrectFirstTime == true){
            var CFT = 0;
            for (QNum=0; QNum<State.length; QNum++){
                if (State[QNum] != null){
                    if (State[QNum][0] >= 1){
                        CFT++;
                    }
                }
            }
            FB += '<br />' + CorrectFirstTime + ' ' + CFT + '/' + QsToShow;
        }
```

All the Javascript here is pre-coded so I am trying my best to hack it. I am however struggling to work out how to pass the variable RealScore to a MySql database via PHP.

There are similar questions here on stackoverflow but none seem to help me.

By the looks of it AJAX seems to hold the answer, but how do I implement this into my JS code?

RealScore is only given a value after the quiz is complete, so my question is how do I go about posting this value to php, and beyond to update a field for a particular user in my database on completion of the quiz?

Thank you in advance for any help, and if you require any more info just let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Storing data using AJAX (without JQuery)**

What you are trying to do can pose a series of security vulnerabilities, it is important that you research ways to control and catch these if you care about your web application's security. These security flaws are outside the scope of this tutorial.

**Requirements:**

- You will need your MySQL database table to have the fields "username" and "score"

What we are doing is writing two scripts, one in `PHP` and one in `JavaScript` (JS). The JS script will define a function that you can use to call the PHP script dynamically, and then react according to it's response.

The PHP script simply attempts to insert data into the database via `$_POST`.

To send the data to the database via AJAX, you need to call the Ajax() function, and the following is the usage of the funciton:

```
// JavaScript variable declarations
  myUsername = "ReeceComo123";
  myScriptLocation = "scripts/ajax.php";
  myOutputLocation = getElementById("htmlObject");

// Call the function
  Ajax(myOutputLocation, myScriptLocation, myUsername, RealScore);
```

So, without further ado...

***JavaScript file:***

```
/**
 * outputLocation - any HTML object that can hold innerHTML (span, div, p)
 * PHPScript - the URL of the PHP Ajax script
 * username & score - the respective variables
 */

function Ajax(outputLocation, PHPScript, username, score) {

    // Define AJAX Request
    var ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Define how AJAX handles the response
    ajaxReq.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (ajaxReq.readyState==4 && xml.status==200) {
                // Send the response to the object outputLocation
                document.getElementById(outputLocation).innerHTML = ajaxReq.responseText;
        }
    };

    // Send Data to PHP script
    ajaxReq.open("POST",PHPScript,true);
    ajaxReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxReq.send("username="username);
    ajaxReq.send("score="score);
}
```

***PHP file*** (you will need to fill in the MYSQL login data)**:**

```
<?php
    // MYSQL login data
    DEFINE(MYSQL_host,  'localhost');
    DEFINE(MYSQL_db,    'myDatabase');
    DEFINE(MYSQL_user,  'mySQLuser');
    DEFINE(MYSQL_pass,  'password123');

    // If data in ajax request exists
    if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["score"])) {
        // Set data
        $myUsername = $_POST["username"];
        $myScore = intval($_POST["score"]);
    } else
        // Or else kill the script
        die('Invalid AJAX request.');

    // Set up the MySQL connection
    $con = mysqli_connect(MYSQL_host,MYSQL_user,MYSQL_pass,MYSQL_db);

    // Kill the page if no connection could be made
    if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));

    // Prepare the SQL Query
    $sql_query="INSERT INTO ".TABLE_NAME." (username, score)";
    $sql_query.="VALUES ($myUsername, $myScore);";

    // Run the Query
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        echo "Score Saved!"; // Return 0 if true
    else
        echo "Error Saving Score!"; // Return 1 if false

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Reece this is a really useful and detailed answer!

Comment: No worries Simon!

If you pursue AJAX in the future, you might like to try `jQuery`, a JavaScript library that can make things like organising the DOM (Document Object Model) and calling AJAX scripts not only simpler, but quicker to implement. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Call simple a Script with the parameter `score`.

```
"savescore.php?score=" + RealScore
```

in PHP Side you save it

```
$score = isset ($_GET['score']) ? (int)$_GET['score'] : 0;
$db->Query('INSERT INTO ... ' . $score . ' ...');
```

You could call the URL via Ajax or hidden Iframe.

Example for Ajax

```
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "/savescore.php?score=" + RealScore,
        type: "GET"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        alert("Save successfull");
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Error on Saving");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use these function for ajax without JQuery its just a javascript function doesnt work in IE6 or below. call this function with the right parameters and it should work.

```
//div = the div id where feedback will be displayed via echo.
//url = the location of your php script
//score = your score.
function Ajax(div, URL, score){
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest(); //sets xmlrequest
    xml.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xml.readyState==4 && xml.status==200){
            document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=xml.responseText;//sets div
        }
    };
   xml.open("POST",URL,true); //sets php url
   xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xml.send("score="score);   //sends data via post
}

//Your PHP-script needs this.
$score = $_POST["score"]; //obtains score from POST.
//save your score here
echo "score saved"; //this will be displayed in the div set for feedback.
```

so call the javascript function with the right inputs, a div id, the url to your php script and the score. Then it will send the data to the back end, and you can send back some feedback to the user via echo.